# Why does the bot spam the console on startup?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

For some reason when i start my bot, it just starts spamming the console log. I have it set so when my bot is online it prints a message in the console so i know it's online. However, it's just being spammed over and over again at weird intervals for no reason.

Here is my code for when it starts up:

```
    client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.username} is now online!`)
        client.user.setActivity("over the server", {
            type: "WATCHING"
          });
        
});
```

so it just doesn't make any sense to me, for why it would just start spamming my console log. Is this a common issue? does it happen under a certain case? please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it doesn't do anything particular in the console.
I think your issue come form your internet connection :  if the bot keeps deconnecting and reconnecting due to your Internet, the `client.on("ready", () => {` will be executed multiple times.
if you still want to keep the console.log, you can try to fix it manually with an if statement :

```
var firstTimeConnecting = 1
client.on("ready", () => {
    if (firstTimeConnecting = 1){
        console.log(`${client.user.username} is now online!`)
        firstTimeConnecting = 0
    }
    client.user.setActivity("over the server", {
        type: "WATCHING"
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, it was probably as you said, an internet issue. I used this code anyways just in case. didn't really do anything and still spams but whatever, ill just live with it. doesn't really affect the rest of my code though

Comment: Update, i think it was network based, it stopped spamming now. Thank you :) im still using ur code though. still a good help.